# How to fetch the row and column number of error

Tags: yacc

How to fetch the row and column number of error (i.e which part of string does not follow the grammar rules)?
I am using yacc parser to check the grammar.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'd better read the [dragon book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886) and the [aho book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201000229) that explain and show example of how to write a lex/yacc based compiler.

In order to get line/column of the error, you shall make your lexer preserve the column and line. So in your lexer, you have to declare two globals, `SourceLine` and `SourceCol` (of course you can use better non-camel cased names).

In each token production, you have to calculate the column of the produced token, for that purpose I use a macro as follows:

```
#define Return(a, b, c)    \
{\
    SourceCol = (SourceCol + yyleng) * c; \
    DPRINT ("## Source line: %d, returned token: "a".\n", SourceLine); \
    return b; \
}
```

and the token production, with that macro, is:

```
"for" { Return("FOR", FOR, 1);
```

then to keep lines, for each token that makes a new line, I'm using:

```
{NEWLINES}     {
    BEGIN(INITIAL);
    SourceLine += yyleng;
    Return("LINE", LINE, 0);
}
```

Then in your parser, you can get `SourceCol` and `SourceLine` if you declare those as extern globals:

```
extern unsigned int SourceCol;
extern unsigned int SourceLine;
```

and now in your `parse_error` grammar production, you can do:

```
parse_error : LEXERROR
{ 
    printf("OMG! Your code sucks at line %u and col %u!", SourceLine, SourceCol); 
}
```

of course you may want to add `yytext`, handle a more verbose error message etc.. But all that's up to you!